# What do we know about the ultimate fate of the Borg?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

The overwhelming impression that one gets while watching *Star Trek: Voyager* is that the Borg will win in the Delta Quadrant. With only a handful of exceptions, that are vastly superior to everything else that we see there. But what do we actually know about their ultimate fate? All that I can think of that can be said for certain is that we've seen enough episodes that are set in the far future to know that the Federation will probably survive, implying that the Alpha Quadrant isn't totally lost yet.

Answers from any source that can claim even the remotest sense of officiality are allowed. I don't recall this question ever being answered in the main shows, so feel free to stretch out in to the licensed works.

Comment: The Voth are presumably holding their own, given that their tech is a) juicy and delicious but b) hasn't been assimilated despite c) living on their doorstep.

Comment: not film/tv canon but the "Star Trek: Destiny" trilogy of books from the mid 2010's is a fantastic cross generational look at Borg origins and well...destiny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Star Trek: [Destiny](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Destiny) is a trilogy by David Mack [released](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53559-star-trek-destiny) in 2008.

> Set in February 2381, the trilogy is a crossover event featuring characters from Star Trek: The Next Generation, Star Trek: Deep Space Nine, Star Trek: Voyager, Star Trek: Titan and, as announced by Marco Palmieri, "elements from Trek's past, coming together in an ambitious tale that will shape the future of the Star Trek universe."

The trilogy deals with both the birth and end of the Borg with their ultimate fate being;

> “There are no more Borg,” Hernandez said. “Not here, or in the Delta Quadrant, or anywhere else, for that matter. There are only Caeliar.” Her beatific mien gave way to a broad smile. “And if you’ll excuse us, we have a new mission to begin.” Dax edged forward and said, “What mission?” “To find and protect cultures of peace and nonviolence—so that perhaps someday in the distant future, the meek really can inherit the universe.”

Comment: Does this have an in-universe date?

Comment: @J.Mini 2381 for the main action. Some plot threads cross substantial amounts of time. None really 'within' tv canon periods.

Comment: I'll not accept this yet, but I suspect that unless something in the Discovery era contradicts it, this'll be correct.

Comment: @J.Mini - as I said in my comment when I referenced this novel, it's non-canon (but still fantastic)

Answer (score 4):

There is [that one disabled Borg cube in *Star Trek: Picard*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Artifact_(Borg_cube)), which the Romulan Free State was studying (as of 2399). Maybe they figured out how to replicate the process that disabled it, and then used that to wipe the Borg out.

We haven’t yet heard a mention of the Borg in the 32nd century in *Star Trek: Discovery*, although [transwarp conduits](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transwarp_conduit) (which the Borg used back in the 24th century) were still in existence, albeit apparently littered with ship debris.

If all Borg ships had dilithium on board, and if the Borg lived exclusively on their ships, it’s possible they wiped out by the Burn. It’s hard to imagine a Borg cube being that vulnerable to dilithium explosion though.

Answer (score 3):

Taking into account Janeway's actions in *Voyager's* "Unimatrix Zero" and the *other* Janeway in the "Endgame", it is possible that Borg has been destroyed as a cohesive "nation". It is unclear if the Unicomplex's destruction was caused by the neurolytic pathogen or was a quarantine attempt of sorts, but USS Voyager also destroyed the transwarp network which was another huge factor of the Borg superiority. It is unclear how much of a network, though. It all depends on the interpretation, of which one possibility is 100%, as it was The Queen's responsibility to maintain said network. But then again, in 2373 (technically 2063) Data destroyed Queen the first time, without, seemingly, much impact on the Collective.

In addition *First Contact* proves definitely that Starfleet has the means to effectively resist the Borg to some extent, so expectation is Alpha Quadrant will survive the Collective just fine.

As mentioned, I'm not sure that The Borg Collective exists anymore, but there are definitely cells of the Borg "species" here and there, consisting of beings freed from the Collective before the Unicomplex's destruction, scattered across all four (definitely three, not sure of Beta, but I think Borg had a transwarp coundit terminal there, too) Quadrants. It's possible that they, along with The Voth (as pointed out by Valorum), Species 8472 and possibly equivalents of Species 116 (sufficiently advanced to resist Borg on one-on-one basis) will successfully resist The Collective. After all, USS Voyager surveyed less than 10% of Delta Quarant, so assumption of above is more than reasonable.